# Themes in Tailwind CSS are not working with Webpack and React

Tags: reactjs, webpack, tailwind-css

I want to switch the theme dynamically in my React project and my react app is build and served using Webpack. So I took inspiration from this [starter app](https://github.com/bandrewfisher/theming-react-components.git). This repo contains the example of switching between two themes at run time and is built using Craco. I tried to migrate from Craco to Webpack ([Webpack sample](https://github.com/bannarisoftwares/tailwind-theme-webpack-issue.git)).

After migrating to Webpack, theme switching is stopped working. When I inspect using the Chrome debugger, the code is changing, but the colors are not reflected in this change.

Can anyone help to resolve the issue? Thanks in advance.

- [carco sample](https://github.com/bandrewfisher/theming-react-components.git) -> https://github.com/bandrewfisher/theming-react-components.git
- [webpack sample](https://github.com/bannarisoftwares/tailwind-theme-webpack-issue.git) -> https://github.com/bannarisoftwares/tailwind-theme-webpack-issue.git

Answer (score 0):

This is working for `tailwind css 2.X version`, not working for `tailwind css 3.X version`

Seems like need to add for  `tailwind css 2.X version`

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
  ],
}
```

in `postcss.config.js`

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = {
 plugins: {
    'postcss-import': {},
     autoprefixer: {},
     tailwindcss: {},
 }
}
```

does this work for you?